# ROS on BeagleBone Issues

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, beaglebone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get ROS Fuerte on a BeagleBone. I've gone through both these processes:

http://williametter.com/portfolio/projects/ros-on-beaglebone/

http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu/Source

but nothing ever builds in the opt folder. What am I missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61312/ros-on-beaglebone-issues/) by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 160 on 2013-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi TJump

I wasn't able to follow willametter's too well but I've successfully built ros fuerte on beagle bone. See this [answer.](http://answers.ros.org/question/58966/ros-on-beaglebone/#59064)

Peter

---

Originally posted by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) with karma: 1493 on 2013-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on 2013-04-23**:
Hi Peter,

I have been looking at the answer you pointed to. I have not gotten to the Level 2 install as I have not had success with the Level 1. I've spent most of the day on installing Ubuntu issues and options. I should get back to ROS install tomorrow and I will report back what I find. Thanks for your post.

**Comment by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on 2013-04-23**:
have a look at claus qr's tutorial,(is a link in my link) it covers the ubuntu install as well.

**Comment by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on 2013-06-22**:
Hi Peter,

Your links made for a good start. I also found the following link (http://sysadminfixes.wordpress.com/2013/03/18/ros-on-beaglebuntu/comment-page-1/)  that highligted how to get ROS Groovy on the Beagle so I moved to the Groovy install rather than Fuerte.